# ¿ Cómo recorrer una lista con FOR?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio con FOR y una lista, llevo ya 3 dias pillado, el ejercicio no es dificil pero no lo pillo, os lo paso:

Escribe un programa que reciba una lista con nombres, una posición de origen (p) y una canitdad (n), y que imprima por pantalla el mensaje "Querido XXX me alegro de verte" por los n nombres que se encuentran a partir de la posción p.

Es decir, si la variable p es 2 pues mostrará dos frases con un nombre diferente de la lista cada una.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
lista=["Marc","Alex","David","Pedro","Raul"]
p=1
n=4
for nom in lista:
    print ("Querido",nom,"me alegro de verte")
```

El resultado es pareciod pero no esta bien

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Marc. Las preguntas que son tareas académicas han de venir acompañadas del código y/o un resumen de lo intentado hasta el momento, mostrando una duda concreta en base a ello para que se adecuen a las normas del sitio. Te recomiendo mirarte [tour], [ask] y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para conocer un poco mejor el sitio y cómo realizar buenas preguntas. Hay varias formas de abordar el problema, desde un `for` con `range` e indexación, un `for in` con slicing de listas, etc. Un saludo.

Comment: hola @Marc, deberías de poner el código que has intentando, ya que este no es un sitio para realizarle las tareas a otros programadores.

Comment: ¿Cual es la salida que deberias obtener segun la entrada que proporcionas?

Comment: No proporciono ninguna entrada, simplemente tendria que recorrer el bucle y depende de el valor que tenga la variable n me mostrara X frases con X nombres, no sé si me explico.

Comment: Prueba con lo siguiente: `lista=["Marc","Alex","David","Pedro","Raul"]
p=1
n=4
for i in range(p, n+1):
    print ("Querido",lista[i],"me alegro de verte")`

Comment: Marc ¿Qué se supone que debe pasar si se proporciona un valor `p + n` que supere el número de elementos de la lista? Por ejemplo, en tu caso para `n = 3` y `p = 3` ¿O no existe esta posibilidad? Por otro lado, ¿la posición `p` se da de acuerdo a los indices de la lista (el primer elemento, "Marc", es `p = 0`) o se empieza a enumerar por 1?

Comment: Se empieza a numerar por 0, la variable que indica el primer nombre de la lista es la variable "p" y la variable "n" indica el numero de nombres que queremos. Osea, si p=3 y n=4 quiere decir que mostrara el primer nombre empezando desde la posición 3 y n no dira la canitdad de frases que queremos.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal Marc, podrías intentar con lo siguiente:

```
lista = ["Juan", "Pedro", "Hugo", "Alberto", "Martin"]
p = 1
n = 4
for nom in lista[p:n]:
    print ("Bienvenido " + nom + " me alegro de verte")
```

lo anterior te daría como resultado algo como esto:

```
Bienvenido Pedro me alegro de verte
Bienvenido Hugo me alegro de verte
Bienvenido Alberto me alegro de verte
```

así si mueves los valores de `p` o `n` dependiendo de ellos serán las posiciones de la lista que te arroje, espero te sea útil, Saludos!!

Comment: Ten en cuenta que aunque la idea es correcta no se hace lo que el op quiere. Se desea obtener `n` elementos empezando por el elemento con índice`p`, con tu código muestras los elementos comprendidos entre los indices `p` y `n - 1` ambos incluidos, que no es lo mismo. El límite derecho del slicing ha de ser por tanto `p + n` Considera también explicar como funciona el slicing de listas para que la pregunta quede completa y no se reduzca solo a código. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Apoyándome en el código anterior y leyendo la observación que realizo **FjSevilla** realice este código y si funciona de la manera que tu quieres según yo.

```
lista = ["Juan", "Pedro", "Hugo", "Alberto", "Martin","Aldo"]
p = 1
n = 4

for i in range(n+1):
    print ("Bienvenido " +  lista[p]+ " me alegro de verte")
    p=p+1
```

*Solo quiero aclarar que puedes tener un error, si el valor de n es mayor al numero de valores que están en tu lista te marcara un error y es por que estarás fuera del rango que tiene tu lista.*

Recuerda que tus arreglos empiezan desde la posición 0 a menos que se lo cambies, por lo tanto tu lista será de esta manera

```
lista = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

tu querías iniciar desde el valor de **p** que seria 1 y a partir de ese valor mostrarias los siguientes 4 valores

Entonces el programa te marcaria un error ya que 1+4=5 y tu en tu arreglo solo tienes hasta el 4 te faltaria un valor para que te mostrara lo demás por eso yo le agregue a tu lista el nombre de "Aldo" para que me lo mostrara también y con esto poder cumplir bien con la condición

```
lista = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

debes de poner una condición donde **n** no supere el número de valores que tiene tu lista, Espero que le entiendas a todo lo que te puse saludos jajaja

Comment: No es una buena idea porque el rango definido no tiene ninguna relación con la longitud del arreglo.

Answer (score -2):

Utiliza

```
p = 0
n = -1
for fecha in fechas_de_pago[p:n]:
```

El **-1** indica el último  valor de tu lista, así no tendrás errores..